# Webpack generating [hash].worker.js file when packaging custom library

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-component

I'm trying to create a library of reusable react components for our internal use.

Webpack is bundling the output - which *should* be a single file.  But it's actually putting out the bundle.js that I'd expect *plus* a file called [some_hash].worker.js.

I'm not sure how to force webpack to include that "worker" file with the single bundle that I'm asking it for.

The webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const DIST_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist");
const SRC_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src");
const APP_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.js");
const BASE_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname);
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = ({ appPath = APP_PATH, distPath = DIST_PATH }) => ({
  context: BASE_PATH,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: distPath,
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', SRC_PATH],
    alias: {
      'react': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-dom'),
    }
  },
  externals: {
      // Don't bundle react or react-dom
      react: {
        commonjs: "react",
        commonjs2: "react",
        amd: "React",
        root: "React"
      },
      "react-dom": {
        commonjs: "react-dom",
        commonjs2: "react-dom",
        amd: "ReactDOM",
        root: "ReactDOM"
      }
  },
  entry: {
    bundle: appPath,
  },
  output: {
    path: distPath,
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    library: 'internal-components',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            plugins: [
              '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
              '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
              [ '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true } ],
              [ '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { 'loose': true } ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: [
              '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
              '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
              ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {'legacy': true}],
              ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", {'loose': true}]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    })
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the [worker-loader plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader#inline) with inline to handle the bundling -

```
rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        use: {
           loader: 'worker-loader',
           options: { inline: true, fallback: false }
        }
      }
    ]
```

That said, there are several open issues on Github surrounding using the worker as a `blob`, so YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are using webpack 3 and above, chunking of the bundle is automatically done for you. In the SplitChunks Plugin documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#defaults) it is actually stated how this behaves.

So because of this you might need to scan your code and check for this conditions. Also it's good to know if you are asynchrously importing the some module? That might signal webpack to make it into a separate chunk.